# iphone doesn't refresh the localized icon after you change language setting !

Tags: iphone

I manage to localized app icon and app name for different languages.I found the icon changes depending on the language setting on the iphone only when the first time when you install the app from xcode.

after that, if i change the language setting, the app icon stay the same but only the app name changes to the localized one.

Anyone has an idea is there is way of solving the problem? it seems iphone doens't refresh the icon after you change the language setting.

Tony

Comment: Did you try to reboot your device after changing the locale settings?

Answer (score 0):

I am going through the same problem right now and my conclusion is you are right. There seems to be no way as of now to change the icon on the fly with the language settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning (**Build > Clean** or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) before changing the language setting and rebuilding your entire project? I find doing that fixes my app icons all the time. Also, be sure you're changing your iPhone Simulator language settings and not your Mac OS X language settings.